# Failed to validate schema due to following error(s): [Does not match format 'regex']

Tags: regex, jsonschema

I'm trying to submit a JSON Schema (draft-04) to AWS EventBridge, but I'm getting an error with my value for `pattern`, ie:

```js
pattern: "^(?:(?:(?:https?|ftp):)?\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z0-9\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}][a-z0-9\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}_-]{0,62})?[a-z0-9\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]\.)+(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,}\.?))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$%iuS"
```

(I've taken the string value from an established regex pattern for validating URL's - https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294 )

When I try to submit this I get an error from `EventBridge`:

```
Failed to validate schema due to following error(s): [Does not match format 'regex']
```

I've tried replacing all of the backslashes (`\`) with double backslashes (`\\`) and I've also tried replacing `\x` with `\u`. I still get the same error. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

What you've tried should work. My guess is that you missed a `\` that needed to be a `\\`.

Here's what I got taking the steps you tried and the regex compiles successfully for me.

```json
"pattern": "^(?:(?:(?:https?|ftp):)?\\/\\/)(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\\.254|192\\.168)(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\\.(?:1[6-9]|2\\d|3[0-1])(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z0-9\\u00a1-\\uffff][a-z0-9\\u00a1-\\uffff_-]{0,62})?[a-z0-9\\u00a1-\\uffff]\\.)+(?:[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]{2,}\.?))(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\\S*)?$%iuS"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! When I copy and paste your code into the Create Schema page of EventBridge I get `invalid character '.' in string escape code`. So I've replaced the identified `\.` with `\\.`, and tried again. Now I get this error: `Failed to validate schema due to following error(s): [Does not match format 'regex']`. How have you managed to get it working?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I missed an escape. As for the regex not matching, I'm not going to go through it in detail, but the only part that looks suspicious to me are the characters after the `$`. I'm guessing this is a way to declare flags in some regex dialects, but otherwise it would just be characters that need to match after the end of the line (`$`). Since that's not possible, the regex always fails. I suggest dropping everything after `$` and try again. Otherwise I suggest opening another question to debug your regex.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I spent most of Friday trying to parse it all to discover what the issue was. It looks like JSON Schema Draft-04 doesn't accept certain Regex that are generally accepted in javascript. For example negative lookaheads (ie, `{!x}`) cause an error. I'll put a full answer in to describe what I've learned.

Comment: Ah, I see. This problem is explained here, https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/regular_expressions.html. It's not that draft-04 doesn't support it, it's just that some validators can't support certain features because of the regex engines that are available in the language the validator is written in.

Comment: Yeah I read this this too, and was confused that it says that negative lookaheads are acceptable, eg `(?!x)`, but when I put anything of the sort into my schema it gets rejected. Seems like certain regex is accepted in theory but not really useable in practice. Thanks again for diving deeper!

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out some of the problems, but I think it will take me many hours to work out a solution with this method. I'm going to use an alternative approach and not use the `pattern` keyword at all. What I've learned:

- Negative lookaheads aren't accepted by JSON Schema (or certainly not JSON Schema Draft 04 specifically). If we want to exclude patterns using regex, we need to use the ["not" keyword](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#id8).
- It looks like the method of referencing unicode characters is not acceptable. It should be `[a-z\\u00a1-\\uffff]`, and not `[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]` (credit to @Jason Desrosiers) The `u00a1-uffff` is telling regex to include all [unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) (from inverted exclamation "¡" and beyond). I've tested on https://regex101.com/r/mV0iS3/1 and found that the `\x` notation is rejected. Trying `\u{xxxx}` with the curly brackets is also rejected.